# Read only SAS view(on double click too)

Tags: view, sas, locking

We have SAS datasets, for which many people have access to read and write. Many a times user click those tables and open. Table gets locked. To circumvent this problem, I tried to created views in same library, if people double click the view it opens table and locks the table again.

One solution I am thinking of to create view in  new library with access=read only option.

Is there read only view option, where in someone double clicks and table does not lock the table. Is it possible to create this view in same library.

Comment: show the `LIBNAME` statement the people are using.  Did you try the libname option `ACCESS=READONLY`. Is the folder on a network share ? Do the users start SAS with a common `autoexec.sas` ?

Comment: just updated my question. Not yet, but that is what, I am going to try tomorrow, but there is lot of people who update and insert into those tables, because nature of work

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a new method for updating data. Do you have a license for `SAS/Share`?  Can you create a relational database to store the data in? Oracle? postgres?

Comment: I do not know whether we have license for SAS/share. I will check this out tomorrow.  I am not sure whether team wants to store data in relational databases, because when I suggested the same, the team showed least interest.

Comment: I'd suggest implementing policy that people load the data to their SAS. (Also good idea in general that people do not have 'oops' access to production datasets)

Comment: @tom  we do not have a SAS/share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had to deal with this problem in an environment where we didn't have SAS/SHARE. My solution was to write a batch job that ran at regular intervals doing the following:

1. Divert the log to a text file.
2. Attempt to lock the table using a `lock` statement.
3. Release the lock immediately if successful.
4. Parse the log file using a data step.
5. Extract the usernames of anyone locking the table.
6. Send an email to all users of the table notifying them that user X was locking it.

Updates to the table only took a fraction of a second each, so although it was possible to catch someone making a legitimate update (or prevent them from doing so), this was very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the best way around this is to create a simple 'data viewer' web application.  If you have a mid-tier and a stored process server then you are ready to go, it should only a couple of hours if you have basic javascript / html knowledge.

I wrote a detailed guide for building web apps using SAS in this sgf [paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/1091-2017.pdf), and a quick summary in this [blog post](https://www.rawsas.com/2015/12/building-web-apps-with-sas/).

The hard part will be convincing your users to use the web app instead of client tools for reading the data!

In the long term it is really best to avoid using SAS datasets and use an actual database instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create views for those datasets in the same library, but save them to a new SAS folder and give the users read only access to the folder & views. And educate your users about SAS table locks so that they wont get put off if they see lock errors.

If you want users to able to write to those tables, then I recommend having a control framework or process in place.

Example Process:

- Users have to submit their code or the data that they want to add / edit,
- As an admin you apply those changes in batches / once a week or a day.

Example Control Frame Work:
All tables should be edited / write to using Stored Processes

- Create Stored Processes that checks the table lock before edit / write to the tables,
- Users will use the SP to write to the tables,
- If two users run the same SP at the same time: The second SP  to run will see the lock flag and print a message to the user to run the SP again in few mins.